# Event Handler in Winform

Tags: c#, winforms, event-handling

I'm new to using event handler in Winforms.

What I'm trying to do is take a screen shot of my desktop using the mouse to dictate the area to capture, then have this image shown in a picture. I was advised to use an event handler to do this in another post but I'm having a real issue trying to get this to work. Could someone please look over what I've done and tell me what is I've done wrong?

Failing that, point me in the right direction to get this fixed?

First off, my screen capture code:

```
 class ScreenCapture
{
    public delegate void StatusUpdateHandler(object sender, ProgressEventArgs e);
    public static event StatusUpdateHandler OnUpdateStatus;

    public static bool saveToClipboard = true;

     public  static void CaptureImage(bool showCursor, Size curSize, Point curPos, Point SourcePoint, Point DestinationPoint, Rectangle SelectionRectangle, string FilePath, string extension)
     {
         using (Bitmap bitmap = new Bitmap(SelectionRectangle.Width, SelectionRectangle.Height))
         {
             using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(bitmap))
             {
                 g.CopyFromScreen(SourcePoint, DestinationPoint, SelectionRectangle.Size);

                 if (showCursor)
                 {
                     Rectangle cursorBounds = new Rectangle(curPos, curSize);
                     Cursors.Default.Draw(g, cursorBounds);
                 }
             }

             if (saveToClipboard)
             {

                  Image img = (Image)bitmap;
                      Clipboard.SetImage(img);

                 if (OnUpdateStatus == null) return; 

                    ProgressEventArgs args = new ProgressEventArgs(img);
                     OnUpdateStatus(this,args);



                 // this is where the screen capture is stored.
                 // it is this image I want pass to the image box





             }
             else
             {
                 switch (extension)
                 {
                     case ".bmp":
                         bitmap.Save(FilePath, ImageFormat.Bmp);
                         break;
                     case ".jpg":
                         bitmap.Save(FilePath, ImageFormat.Jpeg);
                         break;
                     case ".gif":
                         bitmap.Save(FilePath, ImageFormat.Gif);
                         break;
                     case ".tiff":
                         bitmap.Save(FilePath, ImageFormat.Tiff);
                         break;
                     case ".png":
                         bitmap.Save(FilePath, ImageFormat.Png);
                         break;
                     default:
                         bitmap.Save(FilePath, ImageFormat.Jpeg);
                         break;
                 }
             }


         }


     }


}


 public class ProgressEventArgs : EventArgs
{
    public  Image { get; private set; }
    public ProgressEventArgs( Image img)
    {
        Image = img;
    }
}
```

And the code in my form1 class:

```
  public partial class ControlPanel : Form
{
    public EventHandler<ScreenCapture> capture;
    private ScreenCapture _screenCap;

    public ControlPanel()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        _screenCap = new ScreenCapture();
        _screenCap.OnUpdateStatus += new ScreenCapture.StatusUpdateHandler(SetImage);
    }

    private void SetImage(object sender, ProgressEventArgs e)
    {
        // the image box I want the image to be passed to
       // imagePreview.Image = e.OnUpdateStatus;
        SetImage(e.Image);
    }

    private void btn_CaptureArea_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        this.Hide();
        Form1 form1 = new Form1();
        form1.InstanceRef = this;
        form1.Show();

    }


}
```

I've never used event handlers like this before so I'm a little out of my depth.

*edit*

Sorry forgot to add more detail to my issue. Though the main error is still that my program no longer works as it did before with this new code. I still want the image captured to be displayed in the picture box in my form1.

At the moment I have 8 errors with my event handling code. In the following section of code:

```
 public class ProgressEventArgs : EventArgs
{
    public readonly Image { get; private set; }
    public ProgressEventArgs( Image img)
    {
        Image = img;
    }
}
```

My compiler does not like the get or set. As my compliler claims

> Invalid token ';' in class, struct, or interface member declaration

Then, in the line beneath, ProgressEventArgs gets the following error:

> Expected class, delegate, enum, interface, or struct
>   But my thinking was that it was already in the class. So I'm really confused by this error.

Comment: `Tell me what I've done wrong`? But we need to know what your problem is first (in detail)?

Comment: Updated code to reflect my changes.

Comment: Such errors are related to your syntax, it means you lack some `punctuations` such as `}, ;, {, ...` You should try focus your prompt to the beginning `{` of your classes to see if the other `}` are hight-lighted at right position, with that way you can find if you missed some brackets ... and fix it yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like you really need to get a book that covers the basics of C#.  Because there are all sorts of issues scattered about your code.  We've all been there -- just because you're an experienced programmer doesn't mean you won't get tripped up by the nuances.

### ScreenCapture

Your class has many `static` members, but you're instantiating `ScreenCapture` in `ControlPanel`.  I would remove any `static` declarations, or don't bother instantiating it.

*Removing Statics*:

```
public event StatusUpdateHandler OnUpdateStatus;

public bool saveToClipboard = true;

public void CaptureImage(bool showCursor, Size curSize, // ...
```

You are using `using` to automatically dispose of `bitmap` at the end of scope of the `using`.  Since you want to include it in your event, remove that first `using`.

```
Bitmap bitmap = new Bitmap(SelectionRectangle.Width, SelectionRectangle.Height);
using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(bitmap)) { // ...
```

Now that `bitmap` will not get disposed, you can add at the end of `CaptureImage` your function the code to trigger your event.

```
if (OnUpdateStatus != null) {
    OnUpdateState(this, ProgressEventArgs(img));
}
```

### ControlPanel

If you keep `ScreenCapture` static don't make an instance, and register the event on the class.

```
// _screenCap = new ScreenCapture();
ScreenCapture.OnUpdateStatus += _screen_CapOnUpdateStatus;
```

If you're going to do an instance, you need to subscribe to the event after _screenCap is instantiated.

```
_screenCap = new ScreenCapture();
_screenCap.OnUpdateStatus += _screen_CapOnUpdateStatus;
```

You need to create the subscriber too

```
_screen_CapOnUpdateStatus(object source, ProgressEventArgs e) {
     imagePreview.Image = e.Image;
}
```

### ProgressEventArgs

With your event args remove read only.  It'll be read only outside of the class because of the `private set`.  You also need to get the property a name.  You can use the same name as the Type, but that can cause confusion.  Consider using `CapturedImage`.

```
public Image CapturedImage { get; private set; }
public ProgressEventArgs(Image img)
{
    CapturedImage = img;
}
```

Try these changes and then tackle any remaining compiler issues.

Comment: I want a screen captured image Ive taken and stored in my clipboard to be passed to an image box on my main form. The image is taken using another class on another form. That's my objective.